# Find $\alpha$ between two tangents.

Tags: calculus, geometry

I don't understand how to solve question i. Can anyone explain to me?[image]

Comment: The angle between two lines $y=m_1x+n_1$ and $y=m_2x+n_2$ can be found using the formula $\displaystyle \tan(\alpha)=\left|\frac{m_1-m_2}{1+m_1m_2}\right|$.

Comment: And in order to find the equations for the tangents you would like to look at the derivatives of the respective functions given by the definition of the curves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All we need is the slopes of the two lines at $x=2$. We compute the derivatives to be

$$y_1'(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{4x+1}}$$

$$y_2'(x) = x$$

When $x=2$ we have $y_1'(2)=2/3$ and $y_2'(2)=2$.

The angle $\alpha$ can be found from the slopes using the formula

$$\tan(\alpha)=\left\vert\frac{m_1-m_2}{1+m_1m_2}\right\vert$$

Substituting our values for $m_1$ and $m_2$ we get

$$\tan(\alpha)=\frac{4/3}{1+4/3}$$

$$\alpha=\arctan \frac 4 7\approx 29.74^\circ$$

Answer (score 0):

An easier way would be:
First we find the gradient/slope of both the tangents intersecting at Q.
we find the first derivative of both the curves at Q by differentiating it.

y = (4x+1)^1/2 -> dy/dx = 2(4x+1)^-1/2
when x = 2, the dy/dx is 2/3

y2 = x^2/2 +1  -> dy/dx = x
when x = 2, the dy/dx is 2

And then we use the formula (tan^-1x) - (tan^-1x) of the second curve.

tan^-1(2) = 63.4
tan^-1(2/3) = 33.7

therefore the difference of these two answers would give us alpha.
63.4 - 33.7 = 29.7